# SCORM, What LMS I am using?

Tags: scorm

I have a SCORM wrapper that made in jS. (LMSInitialize, LMSGetValue, LMSSetValue ...)

and I load the SCORM file (index_SCORM.html) using iframe.

that's it.

Am I using any LMS? or I'm just using SCORM wrapper without LMS?

please advice me.

Comment: "questions must demonstrate a minimum understanding of the subject...." as per the StackOverflow guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are using SCORM wrapper without LMS.

From [Wiki Docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_management_system) LMS can track information regarding a course, manage sequencing, track progress etc.

In your case you are only running a SCORM package using SCORM wrapper.